# No GUI during calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, ptam, ethzasl-ptam, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the calibration tool of the ethzasl_ptam package, but I cannot see any GUI appearing. According to their developer's issue tracker, this problem occurs only for non-nvidia users. But I am using a Samsung NP450R4E Laptop with a NVIDIA graphics card.

Here are some greps of my OpenGL setting:

```
long@long:~/Workspaces/catkin$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.38
```

```
long@long:~/Workspaces/catkin$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 710M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 331.38
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.38
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

And here is the dump of roslaunch:

```
SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /cameracalibrator/

PARAMETERS
 * /cameracalibrator/ARBuffer_height: 900
 * /cameracalibrator/ARBuffer_width: 1200
 * /cameracalibrator/AutoInitPixel: 20
 * /cameracalibrator/BundleMEstimator: Tukey
 * /cameracalibrator/Calibrator_BlurSigma: 1.0
 * /cameracalibrator/Calibrator_MeanGate: 10
 * /cameracalibrator/Calibrator_MinCornersForGrabbedImage: 20
 * /cameracalibrator/Calibrator_NoDistortion: 0
 * /cameracalibrator/Calibrator_Optimize: 0
 * /cameracalibrator/Calibrator_Show: 0
 * /cameracalibrator/Cam_cx: 0.50417
 * /cameracalibrator/Cam_cy: 0.51687
 * /cameracalibrator/Cam_fx: 0.795574
 * /cameracalibrator/Cam_fy: 1.25149
 * /cameracalibrator/Cam_s: 0.482014
 * /cameracalibrator/CameraCalibrator_CornerPatchSize: 20
 * /cameracalibrator/CameraCalibrator_MaxStepDistFraction: 0.3
 * /cameracalibrator/CandidateMinSTScore: 70
 * /cameracalibrator/FASTMethod: OAST16
 * /cameracalibrator/GLWindowMenu_Enable: True
 * /cameracalibrator/GLWindowMenu_mgvnMenuItemWidth: 90
 * /cameracalibrator/GLWindowMenu_mgvnMenuTextOffset: 20
 * /cameracalibrator/ImageSizeX: 640
 * /cameracalibrator/ImageSizeY: 480
 * /cameracalibrator/InitLevel: 1
 * /cameracalibrator/MaxKF: 15
 * /cameracalibrator/MaxKFDistWiggleMult: 1
 * /cameracalibrator/MaxPatchesPerFrame: 300
 * /cameracalibrator/MaxStereoInitLoops: 4
 * /cameracalibrator/MinTukeySigma: 0.4
 * /cameracalibrator/NoLevelZeroMapPoints: True
 * /cameracalibrator/TrackerMEstimator: Tukey
 * /cameracalibrator/TrackingQualityFoundPixels: 50
 * /cameracalibrator/UseKFPixelDist: True
 * /cameracalibrator/WiggleScale: 0.1
 * /cameracalibrator/gui: True
 * /cameracalibrator/parent_frame: world
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.7

NODES
  /
    cameracalibrator (ptam/cameracalibrator)

core service [/rosout] found
process[cameracalibrator-1]: started with pid [26423]
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/long/Workspaces/catkin/devel/lib/ptam/cameracalibrator...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Starting program: /home/long/Workspaces/catkin/devel/lib/ptam/cameracalibrator image:=camera/image_raw pose:=pose __name:=cameracalibrator __log:=/home/long/.ros/log/a8fc0c54-172f-11e4-971f-24f5aa6f5f4f/cameracalibrator-1.log
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[ INFO] [1406645466.213345330]: starting CameraCalibrator with node name /cameracalibrator
  Welcome to CameraCalibrator 
  -------------------------------------- 
  Parallel tracking and mapping for Small AR workspaces
  Copyright (C) Isis Innovation Limited 2008 
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffe9b7b700 (LWP 26430)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe937a700 (LWP 26431)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe8b79700 (LWP 26432)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe3fff700 (LWP 26437)]
Gui is on
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
```

Any ideas? Might there be a problem with NVIDIA Optimus?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188192/no-gui-during-calibration/) by [Long Hoang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19849/long-hoang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried it with Bumblebee and make sure that optimus is working, but even with that I did not see any GUI appearing.

So, finally, I just pulled the the original PTAM source code. With that build, I could run the calibration tool (with GUI) and even without using optimus.

As I don't have enough Karma.. you can find some useful Links below in the comments

---

Originally posted by [Long Hoang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19849/long-hoang/) with karma: 38 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Long Hoang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19849/long-hoang/) on 2014-07-31**:
I got the source here:
[www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/PTAM/](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Egk/PTAM/)

And this blog post helped me a lot to get it build (there is an include missing in the code..)
http://hustcalm.me/blog/2013/09/27/ptam-compilation-on-linux-howto/